# How can I extract the nested value from this Javascript/HTML code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

In this code, I want to extract the value "Yes, I am a Speaker"
 through Javascript DOM element. By using getElementById. But, I do not
 know how to access the value as it is nested inside the list element and the list doesn't have any value and attribute. And, in this code only list has a unique id to
 select this element. There are several such blocks of code with unique
 list id. I would appreciate if there is a quick help. I am using
 this for creating GTM custom javascript variable.

```
<li id="u5mH6ZV1aX21" class="container step2" style="width: 232px;">
  <input type="hidden" name="value" value="Yes, I am a smoker" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="letter"><span>A</span></div>
  <span class="label">Yes, I am a smoker</span>
  <span class="tick"></span>
  <div class="aux">
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <div class="bd"></div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Not sure how you get "speaker" from that. Love when someone uses a class="label" and not a <label> element. :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We ask that you do some initial research (could be from books, Google, etc.) and make an attempt at solving your issue first. Then post what you've tried and what *specific* problem you are having here. You will generally not get answers without making an attempt and these kinds of questions are often closed as "off topic" or "too broad". In your case, there are numerous solutions.

Comment: Both the hidden input and the span with class "label" have the text you are trying to get.  It's unclear which you want.

Comment: If you mean "Yes, I am a smoker" from the input element inside the LI you can use document.getElementsByName("value")[0].value

Comment: You should investigate [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) -- using this, you can fetch what I believe you are seeking with `document.querySelector('#u5mH6ZV1aX21>input').value`.

Comment: To start with, the DOM you post here is not well-formatted - the `li` and `input` tags are not closed.  You also never have the text "Yes, I am a Speaker" within the example.  If you meant "Yes, I am a smoker", then it exists twice here, and it's unclear which one you are trying to extract it from - the value of the `input` tag, or the text within the `span` tag?

Comment: @autophage `input` elements don't get closed.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Huh, sure enough!  I knew that it wasn't typical to match it with a separate close tag (since it doesn't contain anything), but was under the impression that it did need to be self terminating (`<input />`) - turns out that's not the case.

Comment: @autophage Self-termination is not required anywhere in HTML. In fact, self-termination isn't even valid syntax in HTML. That's an XHTML/XML thing. Doing it HTML means nothing to the client and the trailing `/` is simply ignored as not being understood.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So select the element by the class or element type

```js
var t1 = document.querySelector("#u5mH6ZV1aX21 input").value
var t2 = document.querySelector("#u5mH6ZV1aX21 .label").textContent
console.log(t1, t2);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="u5mH6ZV1aX21" class="container step2" style="width: 232px;">
    <input type="hidden" name="value" value="Yes, I am a smoker" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="letter"><span>A</span></div>
    <span class="label">Yes, I am a smoker</span>
    <span class="tick"></span>
    <div class="aux ">
      <div class="bg"></div>
      <div class="bd"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've dinged me for answering poor questions that don't even have an attempt in them.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the modern `querySelector` API to select a specific element using the fact that you know the unique ID and the type (or "tagName") of the child element you're trying to access.

[MDN article on querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```
document.querySelector("#u5mH6ZV1aX21 input").value
```

Comment: Please don't provide answers to poor questions that are likely to be closed. It just encourages more poor questions.

Comment: Well, I believe that is just your opinion, my friend. I am here to help people. If you can point me to something in the site guidelines that specifically discourages providing answers to a question like this, I would be surprised but willing to read. The moderation system is in place to promote good questions and answers, so perhaps you could use that instead. I think downvoting perfectly fine answers because of your personal philosophy on the original question is contrary to the spirit of the site. (By the way I don't agree the original Q was all that poor. It was fairly specific and clear)

Comment: It's not my opinion, my friend. Please read ["How to Answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guidelines, specifically the part on "Answer [Well-Asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Questions", which starts off by saying that questions should be thoroughly researched before being asked here. Also, because there is not just one way to answer this question, we have the "Too broad" close reason, which this question also falls into. So no, the OP was not specific and did not meet our standard for a good question. It actually meets our standard for closure as too broad.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, Stack Overflow's "moderation system" isn't just comprised of designated moderators. It consists of its members using the tools provided by the site. Up/Down votes, votes to close, votes to delete, and the ability to flag questions, answers, or comments are all part of that as well. By down voting your answer and providing you with a comment as to why, I *am* using the moderation system.

Comment: Yes, that is what I understand the moderation system as well. I'm still not sure I agree with downvoting answers because you think the question isn't up to standards, but I take your other points.

Comment: It's pretty common to down vote answers to poor questions because we want to discourage answers to poor questions so that we don't attract more poor questions.